# Using a database not generated by rake and scaffold in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using:

```
Rails 2.3.5
Ruby 1.8.7
Windows 7 Home basic 64-bit
```

I'm trying to use a database I acquired using mysqldump, and create functions ADD, EDIT, and DELETE to go with it. Now, when I'm creating the edit function, and i'm using its primary key (productCode) as a parameter, i get this error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PosController#edit
Couldn't find Product without an ID

App Trace:
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1567:in `find_from_ids'
C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:616:in`find'
C:/Users/Aldrin/Documents/Trabaho!/sites/dbSample/app/controllers/pos_controller.rb:13:in `edit'

here's my code:

```
def edit
@product = Product.find(params[:ProductCode])
end

def update
@product = product.find(params[:ProductCode])
if session[:user_id]
            @log = "Welcome Administrator!"
            @logout="logout"
        else
            @log = "Admin Log in"
            @logout=""
        end

respond_to do |format|
  if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
    flash[:notice] = 'product was successfully updated.'
    format.html { redirect_to(@product) }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @product.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

I don't have an :id column in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `productCode` is the primary key in the table then you should tell rails to use it instead of `id`

```
class Product << ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = 'productCode'

end
```

That way standard `find` calls will work, and you won't need to overwrite methods like `to_param` as rails will already have done it for you

Comment: Aldrin, this solution'd work for you! thnx didn't know about this trick!

Comment: aah sorry, my fault, should have proof read my answer it should read `self.primary_key = product code` - have fixed the code in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
def edit
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
end

def update
@product = Product.find(params[:id])
..............................
end
```

**EDIT**

```
def to_param 
    "#{product_code}" 
end

def edit
@product = Product.find_by_product_code(params[:id])
end

def update
@product = Product.find_by_product_code(params[:id])
..............................
end
```

Comment: then overwrite to_param method from your model

Comment: can you explain that further? I'm new to rails.

Comment: thanks for your answer, and it helped. However, I have another error. Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

Comment: if you don't use id, then in all places of your controller you should change find to find_by_product_code, this errors probably occurring from you show action

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9579/discussion-between-aldrin-dela-cruz-and-said-kaldybaev)